# how to properly use Keras imports since it is embedded in TF?

Tags: tensorflow, import, keras, tf.keras

how to i properly import anything from keras within tensorflow?

if I e.g.,

`from tensorflow import keras`

`from keras.layers.core import Dense`

does that import from Keras or from tf.keras?

Comment: `from tensorflow.keras ... import module_i_want`

Comment: I see. When using `from tensorflow.keras.layers.core....` I got an error which was a bit confusing. So using only `from keras import`  uses the old standalone keras?

Comment: Yes, `from keras import` imports from standalone keras.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras Can help you out